# Check if an object exists in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got an array with multiple person-objects in it, this objects look like this:

```
id: 1,
name: 'Max Muster',
email: 'max.muster@example.com',
language: 'German'
```

Now, I've got objects in another array, which doesn't look exactly the same:

```
id: 1,
name: 'Max Muster',
email: 'max.muster@example.com',
language: 'de'
```

I've got a foreach-loop to loop through array 2 and check if the objects exists in array 1.

```
foreach($array2 as $entry) {
    if(existsInArray($entry, $array1)) {
        // exists
    } else {
        // doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Is there a function to check (like my existsInArray()), if my object exists in the array? I just need to check, if the object-id exists, other attributes doesn't matter.

Comment: use `array_diff` to check the both array is same or not.

Comment: As the objects are different, then you can't do a simple comparison to see if they are the same. What qualifies an object from the first array as matching an object from the second array? Same id? Same name? Same email? Same language? Some combination of those?

Comment: Yes, need to convert them Object to array than `array_diff`.

Comment: You could make this a lot easier if you used the id's as the array keys.

Comment: It's just the id, which has to be the same

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the object IDs as keys when you put the objects in the array:

```
$array1[$object->id] = $object;
```

then use `isset($array1[$object->id])` to check if the object already exists in `$array`:

```
if (isset($array1[$object->id])) {
    // object exists in array; do something
} else {
    // object does not exist in array; do something else
}
```

Comment: this looks like it checks by index, but isn't index arbitrary? How does this work?

Comment: [PHP Arrays](https://www.yphp.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) are, in fact, maps/hashes/dictionaries. They associate a numeric or string key to a value of any type. The OP has two sets of objects identified by their `id` attributes. The answer suggests to put the first set of objects in an array and use the `id` as key. When the second set of objects is processed, use the object `id` to find the object with the same `id` in the array. By using the `id` as key (and not a numeric key generated automatically), the object can be identified without scanning the entire array.

Answer (score 5):

It does not, but you can write it:

```
function existsInArray($entry, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $compare) {
        if ($compare->id == $entry->id) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array2 as $entry) {
    if(in_array($entry, $array1)) {
        // exists
    }  else {
    // doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Use in_array to check if that particular object exists in the array

Answer (score 0):

Use `in_array`

```
if(in_array($object, array)) {
   //exists
} else {
   //does not exist
}
```