# Laravel foreach iterate only one time though item that has same ids

Tags: php, laravel

I am retrieving users using many to many relationships. I want to loop through the user only one time that have two entries in pivot.
e.g.

```
 $admin = Admin::first();
 $users = $admin->users;

 foreach($users as $user) {
 //Iterate through users that has different ids
 //Do not iterate over same user twice
}
```

Comment: What stops you from doing an `if`-statement? If the id is not what you need, `continue` in the loop.

Comment: As @ManuelMannhardt suggested, you can store the ids in an array that you looped through, and in each loop you can check if that id exist in the array. If exists -> skip, if not -> do the things you want to do.

Comment: @REd fx2 can you give code example?

Comment: @KamranAli That was a general suggestion for object oriented programming, I do not practice php. But these sites may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572313/in-php-how-can-i-add-an-object-element-to-an-array      and      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524969/check-if-an-object-exists-in-an-array

Comment: @Red fx thank you for your help , actually what I need to show items one time that has duplicate entries in collection object.So it need some programming technique to count items of same ids and take one of them

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code just use all() OR get() instead of first().
Or if you have multiple entries with single admin please share your model code

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the duplicate user entries, it is also possible to avoid the duplicates in the `$admin->users` collection by using the distinct method:

```
$admin = Admin::first();
$users = $admin->users()->distinct()->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects

Comment: i have used that , didn't work for me.I used unique() as well but same issue

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. array_unique($array) was the solution. I pushed user ids to $users array and used array_unique($users).Thanks to php.net.
Ref. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
 <?php
 $input = array(4, "4", "3", 4, 3, "3");
 $result = array_unique($input);
 var_dump($result);
 ?>
```